# Why cant I install @mikro-orm/mariadb

Tags: express, npm, mariadb, mikro-orm, adminjs

Trying to install mikroorm into adminjs. I am using:https://mikro-orm.io/docs/usage-with-adminjs

I ran the command `npm install @mikro-orm/mariadb` as instructed in the guide and it returns

```
npm ERR!     @mikro-orm/mariadb@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-04-11T21_31_08_922Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-04-11T21_31_08_922Z-debug-0.log
```

Log from the error message above:

```
error code ERESOLVE
68 error ERESOLVE could not resolve
69 error
70 error While resolving: [1mcisgo[22m@[1m0.0.0[22m
70 error Found: [1m@mikro-orm/core[22m@[1m4.5.10[22m[2m[22m
70 error [2mnode_modules/@mikro-orm/core[22m
70 error   [35mpeer[39m [1m@mikro-orm/core[22m@"[1m^4.5.0[22m" from [1m@adminjs/mikroorm[22m@[1m2.0.0[22m[2m[22m
70 error   [2mnode_modules/@adminjs/mikroorm[22m
70 error     [1m@adminjs/mikroorm[22m@"[1m^2.0.0[22m" from the root project
70 error
70 error Could not resolve dependency:
70 error [1m@mikro-orm/mariadb[22m@"[1m*[22m" from the root project
70 error
70 error Conflicting peer dependency: [1m@mikro-orm/core[22m@[1m5.6.16[22m[2m[22m
70 error [2mnode_modules/@mikro-orm/core[22m
70 error   [35mpeer[39m [1m@mikro-orm/core[22m@"[1m^5.0.0[22m" from [1m@mikro-orm/mariadb[22m@[1m5.6.16[22m[2m[22m
70 error   [2mnode_modules/@mikro-orm/mariadb[22m
70 error     [1m@mikro-orm/mariadb[22m@"[1m*[22m" from the root project
70 error
70 error Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
70 error this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
70 error to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
71 error
71 error
71 error For a full report see:
71 error C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-04-11T21_31_08_922Z-eresolve-report.txt
72 verbose exit 1
73 timing npm Completed in 3695ms
74 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1681248668965
75 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:loadTrees 1681248668967
76 verbose unfinished npm timer idealTree:buildDeps 1681248669559
77 verbose unfinished npm timer idealTree:#root 1681248669559
78 verbose code 1
79 error A complete log of this run can be found in:
79 error     C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-04-11T21_31_08_922Z-debug-0.log
```

Im not sure what to do here, any help would be appreciated

Comment: include contents of the logs shown, at least the end of them by editing the question.

Comment: updated with the logs

Comment: From that (very obfuscated) log it seems you had MikroORM v4 installed (v4.5.10 to be precise) and you tried to install v5 of the mariadb driver (as that is the latest and you havent specified the version when running `npm install`).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have solved the problem. Used Sequelize instead.